Django request.user isn't using the custom backend at all
I'm coding with a custom user model and a custom backend in Django 5.0 to login with an email.
Here is the backend :
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        print("authenticate called")
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            print(user_id)
            print("get_user called")
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

It's correctly registered in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS, and the user model just has an email field.
The backend works perfectly in my register view using authenticate(request, username=email, password=password), and the login(request, user) works too.
However, if in another view, after a login I try to use request.user, it will always return AnonymousUser.
If I do request.session.values, the user ID is correct.
I can't find anyone having the same issue online, so I hope someone can help me troubleshoot it.
I tried to use request.user with the custom backend, but it's never called.
I also tried to use request.session.values and this time the user ID was correct.
The request.user was supposed to return the current user with my custom model, but it always return AnonymousUser.

As my understanding, you need to create a middlware also to set request.user. I think that's what django do.

@Pycm Do you have a link where I can see an example ? I can't find one unfortunatly.

Did you set AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings.py too? Make sure, that throughout your EmailBackend and views you refer to the correct User model.

Yes. Look here line 22-35 https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca5cd3e3e8e53f15e68ccd727ec8fe719cc48099/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L23  That's how django sets request.user. Line 33.

@Pycm Django will handle the request.user object. Let Django do that and don’t interfere.

ok. but However, if in another view, after a login I try to use request.user, it will always return AnonymousUser. If I do request.session.values, the user ID is correct. he wanted to know how it happens. i mean he could set request.customuser=his_model same as django.

even if you authenticate with a custom backend, request.user  won't be your custom user model. unless you set it so.

@Pycm no, that is not how it works. The AuthenticationMiddleware figures out the appropriate user + backend from the session and uses them. There's no need to reinvent that since it can work fine with custom models, backends, etc.

reinvent that no. you need to change only less than 5 lines in the above file.  no, that is not how it works. but each request is processed individually, how django preserve request.user ? it obviously uses Middleware for that. The AuthenticationMiddleware figures out the appropriate user + backend from the session and uses them. isn't that what I said? not using auth backend as your answer says.

@Pycm you are talking about changing that middleware, what I said means that it is unnecessary to do so. Using a custom user model / backend will totally work with the builtin AuthenticationMiddleware without any changes. The middleware is smart enough to handle those as long as the backend and model are setup properly. Also "you need to change only less than 5 lines in the above file" you shouldn't really be modifying a third party package like that...

Please show us your AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting, AUTH_USER_MODEL setting and your custom user model. You might actually want to skip creating this backend as well, if you've implemented the user model properly the default ModelBackend should be able to handle everything properly.

Behind the scenes, Django maintains a list of “authentication backends” that it checks for authentication. When a call to authenticate() is made, Django tries authenticating across all of its authentication backends in this list.
If the first authentication method fails, Django tries the second one, and so on, until all backends have been attempted. But if one succeeds, Django doesn’t continue.
This means that the order of specifying “authentication backends” is important. Your custom “authentication backend” should be added to the list of AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS [django-docs] in settings.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'python path.to.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]
